# Rails - Updating and deleting content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

EDIT: I managed to delete! i had to define teh instance variable @movies = Movie.find(params[:id]) to the delete method in the controller.

I still can't update though. I get "param is missing or the value is empty: movie"

---

I forgot to add my contrller! sorry!

I'm trying to replicate one of my in class exercises into another app, for practice.

The idea is to be able to add new movies into a database, and get the option to update their info, and delete them as well. I can add new content, but I can't update them or delete them.

Appreciate any inputs I can get.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "movies#index"
  get "/movies", to: "movies#index"
  get "/movies/new", to: "movies#new", as: "new_movie"
  get '/movies/:id', to: "movies#movie_page", as: "movie_page"
  post "/movies", to: "movies#add"
  get "/movies/:id/edit", to: "movies#edit", as: "movie_edit"
  put "/movies/:id", to: "movies#update"
  patch "/movies/:id", to: "movies#update", as: "update_movie"
  delete "/movies/:id", to: "movies#delete", as: "delete_movie"

end
```

Controller

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @movies = Movie.all
    end

    def movie_page
        @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @movies = Movie.new
    end

    def add
        @movies = Movie.create(movie_params)
        redirect_to movies_path
    end

    def edit
        @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @movies.update(movie_params)
        redirect_to @movies, notice: "Shirt was updated."
    end

    def delete
        @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
        @movies.destroy
        # flash[:notice] = "Shirt was deleted."
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Shirt was deleted."
    end

    def movie_params
        params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :year_released)
    end

    # def set_movie
    #   @movies = Movie.find(params[:id])
    # end

end
```

Form partial

```
<%= form_for @movies do |m| %>
    <p>
        <%= m.label :title %><br>
        <%= m.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= m.label :description %><br>
        <%= m.text_field :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= m.label :year_released %><br>
        <%= m.text_field :year_released %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= m.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Movie page html (individual movies, labeled by IDs)**I can't update or Delete, no route matches Delete.

When I press Update - I get param is missing or the value is empty: movie

```
<h1><%= @movies.title %></h1>
<h2>Released on : <%= @movies.year_released %> </h2>
<p> <%= @movies.description %> </p>

<%= link_to "Update", movie_edit_path(@movies) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", movies_path, method: :delete %
```

Edit page *I cant access this link. the form is the problem

```
<h1>Edit <%= @movies.title %> Info </h1>

<%= render "form" %>

<%= link_to "Cancel Edit", movie_edit_path(@movies) %>
```

Many thanks guys

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what error message do you obtain? what do you expect to see and what you actually see?

Comment: Please give it a shot -- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles and figure out all the basic things that you missed.

Comment: You should really use the singular `@movie` when it's just a single movie. This is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def update
  @movie = Move.find(params[:id])
  @movie.update(movie_params)
  redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
end
```

on your routes. all you need is `resources :movies`

you are getting param is empty because you have to pass in the id of the movie to update.

Answer (score 0):

The major issue is that you do not load the variable @movies from the DB before you use it.

```
def update
    @movies.update(movie_params)
    redirect_to @movies, notice: "Shirt was updated."
end


def update
    @movies.find(params[:id])
    @movie.update(movie_params)
    redirect_to @movies, notice: "Shirt was updated."
end
```

Aside from that you have tons of duplication and quite a few idiosyncrasies.

Rails uses these naming conventions for actions:

- index
- show (not movie_page)
- new
- create (not add)
- edit
- update
- destroy (not delete)

You should follow them unless you have a damn good reason not to.

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  # cuts the duplication
  before_filter :set_movie, except: [:new, :index]

  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end

  # GET /movies/:id
  def show
  end

  # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  # POST /movies
  def create
    @movie = Movie.create(movie_params)
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  # GET /movies/edit
  def edit
  end

  # PUT|PATCH /movies/:id
  def update
    @movie.update(movie_params)
    redirect_to @movie, notice: "Shirt was updated."
  end

  # DELETE /movies/:id
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    redirect_to action: :index 
  end

  private 

  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :year_released)
  end

  def set_movie
    # Use the singular form when naming a variable with a single record
    # failure to do so may result in tarring and feathering
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

Comment: Good answer. Minor typo in the update method, should be movie.update, not movies.update